# MySQL slow on SELECT WITH "OR" on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table that has about 3mil rows. And while I use this query to select:

```sql
SELECT order_code, store_debit, total_price
FROM orders
WHERE 4624603 IN (id, pid) AND `status` = -6;
```

or this query (using **OR**)

```sql
SELECT order_code, store_debit, total_price
FROM orders
WHERE (id = 4624603 OR pid = 4624603) AND `status` = -6;
```

and that one took **>17secs**.
But when I separate it into 2 queries:

```sql
SELECT order_code, store_debit, total_price
FROM orders
WHERE id = 4624603 AND `status` = -6;
```

and

```sql
SELECT order_code, store_debit, total_price
FROM orders
WHERE pid = 4624603 AND `status` = -6;
```

it returns results like **instantly**.
How could I optimize the first query to make it runs as fast as the other 2.

Thank you all!

UPDATE:
These are the indexes of the table

```sql
cop_type    payment_type, cod_type, cash_transfer, pid, status, created Normal  BTREE
all_type    payment_type, cash_transfer, pid, status, created   Normal  BTREE
theodoi user_id, pid, payment_type, cash_transfer, status, report_atm, pay_status, created  Normal  BTREE
item_lib    item_id, status, pay_status, payment_type, created  Normal  BTREE
search_phone    phone   Normal  BTREE
search_order_code   order_code  Normal  BTREE
search_order_email  email   Normal  BTREE
order_work  cod_id, status, district, payment_type, pay_status, cash_transfer, cod_type, free_ship  Normal  BTREE
select_hot  province, status, type, created, payment_type, pay_status, item_id  Normal  BTREE
coupon_after_buy    id, pid, status, free_ship  Normal  BTREE
search_ofice    office, created, status, ship_status    Normal  BTREE
search_item item_id, office, created, status, ship_status   Normal  BTREE
idx_ward_id ward_id Normal  BTREE
idx_street  street_id   Normal  BTREE
idx_group_code  group_code, pid Normal  BTREE
idx_paytime payment_time    Normal  BTREE
search_all  pid, status, created    Normal  BTREE
idx_country_type    country_type    Normal  BTREE
idx_book_time   book_time   Normal  BTREE
```

Comment: Index `id` and  `pid`

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with both **OR** and **IN**, and they are both slow

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ: I updated my question. Should I index just id and pid in a new index key? I already have those field in **coupon_after_buy** index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a UNION of the last two? The in/or is probably forcing a table scan.

Comment: Thank you, that works :D I was completely forget about **UNION**.